# What happens with the case sensitive directories and files in an NTFS partition under Windows?

Tags: partitioning, windows, ntfs, filename, case-insensitive

I use Ubuntu since 1,5 years. I upgraded my computer so that's the time for backup, fresh install, etc. I will make a dual boot system, so here is my problem:

I have some (i don't know exactly how many and where) files and directories with special characters which are unsupported by Windows (partially in EXT4 and partially in NTFS partitions). I know files with unsupported characters (like : ? ") cannot be opened in Windows but these files are in safe until the next time when I switch back to Linux.

But what happens those files and directories which have same name and only differs in lower or uppercase letters? For example:
The videos and Videos folders will be merged if I boot from Windows? If yes, what will happen the Somedocument.ods and someDocument.ods and Somedocument.ods files?

Comment: I thought ntfs was case-sensitive

Comment: NTFS is case-preservative, not case-sensitive.

Comment: @ScottGoodgame [**NTFS is case sensitive**](https://superuser.com/a/881813/241386). It's just Win32 subsystem is case-insensitive. It was used by POSIX subsystem in Windows in the past, and now Ubuntu-on-Windows

Answer (score 1):

Nothing happens. They're still there. Explorer can **display** them just fine, but you have ***access*** to only one of them

For example if 2 folders have the same case-insensitive name, then opening either one will show you the same content

[image: folders with same name]

Same to files, you'll only be able to get one of the files

[image: files with same name]

In case a file and a directory with the same name you may get the below error

[image: Case-sensitive file names on Windows]

as in [How can I access case-sensitive paths on Windows (created with Bash-on-Ubuntu-on-Windows)?](https://superuser.com/q/1116625/241386)

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to make Windows case sensitive.  Not sure what it is, maybe POSIX, but I'm afraid that would change many other things.

Comment: The option is stored in [`HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\kernel\ObCaseInsensitive`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39116635/995714). But win32 applications won't use that anyway